# How should I improve my Retopology? Having trouble with creating proper edge loops

Tags: retopology

Using Blender 4.1 and Retopoflow 3.4

I'm beginning to learn retopology for better mesh deformation in animation and have given it a few goes now, but am feeling a little stuck. I'm especially having issues determining proper edge loop amount based on mesh area (for instance the torso doesn't need as many as the hands, etc). I also end up accidentally creating triangles when I want to maintain a quad  focused retopology.

[image]

Here is my in-progress retopology of a basic human sculpt I made, and I'm aware it has several issues. I was wondering if anyone has any advice on where to go from here? I'll attach a few more images of problem areas below as well.[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe choose this topology for the hand:

[image]

And you can clean the body this way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots, but I feel like this gets rid of proper edge flow which is what I’m looking for.

Comment: could you please elaborate?